# Middle box is not in the same position and different size

Tags: css

Im a CSS begginer so please dont laugh! :) I tried almost everthing but it didnt help. My middle box needs to be the same size as the other ones and it needs to be in the same position
[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grb2h.jpg) Please give your opinions and be quick cuz I dont really have a time... Thank you!
Cause my text is too short and I cant upload it i'll add some more text.
And sorry cause I dont speak english really good. One more thing... How can I make these boxes to show slowly when I click the button with Javascript. I dont want it to be in JQuery!

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#left {
 float:left;
 display: block;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #0080ff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 56px;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#middle {
 -moz-box-align: center;
 top: 50%;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -50px;
 display:block;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #0080ff;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
 
#right {
 float:right;
 display: block;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #0080ff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 56px 54px;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size:  cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#left, #middle, #right{
 height: 130px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Moj web</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
<body background="http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<script>
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiv");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>
function showDiver() {
    var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiver");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>
function showDiverer() {
    var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiverer");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<center><div>
<button onclick="showDiv()" style= "margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
<button onclick="showDiverer()" style= "margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
<button onclick="showDiver()" style= "margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
</div></center>
<br>
<br>
<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;">
<div  id="left">
<p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br>
Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br>
Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="welcomeDiver" style="display:none;">
<div id="right">
<p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br>
Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br>
Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="welcomeDiverer" style="display:none;">
<div  id="middle">
<p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br>
Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br>
Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need your HTML code as well, please. As for the fade in, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, try this:

```
.animate {
       -webkit-animation-name: example;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {visibility: hidden;}
    to {visibility: visibile;}
}
```

Javascript:

```
var leftBtn = document.getElementById("Insert Button Id Here");
var leftBox = document.getElementById("left");
leftBtn.onclick = startLeftAnimation;

function startLeftAnimation() {
    leftBox.classList.add("animate");
}
```

CSS Animations should be much cleaner in this case. There is less code involved and it's a lot easier to debug.